# changing the value of selectize without deleting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have an input with selectize and I want when displaying the selected value, to be able to modify part of the displayed value without completely deleting the option. In fact currently I have to completely empty the input to write a new value but I cannot modify the displayed value

Comment: Can you please add your current code to the question so that we can see the context you're working in

Comment: Not quite sure what you need / want to do. If it's something along the lines of - I typed Alaska, but want to delete a few characters and change it to Alabama - that's not possible. SelectizeJS doesn't work like that. Select2 multiselect can do that, but only if you're changing the last option / tag.